# GRPC future vs blocking stub in client

Tags: kotlin, grpc, grpc-java

I'm writing a client application in Kotlin where I need to call a GRPC service that has both a future based and a blocking stub.

In case I choose to go with the future option, I will need at some point to do something like a `CompletableFuture.get()` call, which means I will be blocking anyway.

So, what's the difference between one and the other for this case? Or is it the same?

Comment: Is it really a `Future` that you get from GRPC? Or is it a `CompletableFuture`?

Comment: It's a `ListeneableFuture` that I can (among other things) transform into a `CompletableFuture`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I will need at some point to do something like a CompletableFuture.get() call, which means I will be blocking anyway

Not necessarily. With a `ListenableFuture`, `CompletableFuture`, or other completion-hookable mechanisms, you don't have to block at all. You could register an action to do on completion, or you could wrap them in `suspend` calls to work with coroutines etc.

Also, even if you *did* call `get()` and block, it still allows you to block later than the start of the call, and do other things between the initial call and the `get()`, which would be concurrent with it:

```kotlin
val future = callSomethingWithFuture()
doStuffConcurrently()
val result = future.get()
```

Comment: Sure, that's all true, but in this case I need an actual value, so will probably do a `.get()` immediately. What's the difference between this and using the blocking stub?

Comment: If you really want to call `get` immediately, then I don't think there is much difference with using the blocking stub. You will indeed block the current thread anyway until a result is here. I'm not very familiar with gRPC, but there may also be some overhead in that case with the future+get approach because likely the work is already blocking another thread as well, so you would be blocking 2.

Comment: That said, if you want to work with non-blocking, I'd highly suggest using Kotlin coroutines. This way you can write sequential code that waits for the result, but doesn't block a thread (using `await()` instead of `get()`)

Comment: That would be an option, yes.